# SaltStack: include only one state of a file

Tags: salt-stack

I have a sls file `foo/bar.sls`.

Since running all states takes too long, I would like to call only `foo/bar.sls`.

This is works with `state.sls`.

But one simple state from a different sls file (`root/big.sls`) is needed.

Up to now I have no clue how to do this in salt-stack. I could use "include" but this would include and **execute** all states from `root/big.sls`. That's not what I want.

Compared to python: I want to call one method of a module, not every method of this module.

How to do this with saltstack?

Comment: This is not supported by saltstack according to https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/include.html

You can only include the whole `sls`
With `exclude`, you can specify the state id.

If it's just one simple state, why do you just copy it instead of bothering to use include,

Comment: @laocius Thank you for this commit.  I don't copy+paste. I avoid redundancy. See: https://github.com/guettli/programming-guidelines/blob/master/README.rst#avoid-redundancy

Comment: @laocius If you write your comment as answer, then I can up-vote and accept it.